# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float' in python bar chart

Tags: python, bar-chart

I am trying to plot grouped bar chart i have this data.

```
y1= [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215]
y2=[0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152]
```

i want to plot graph like this with labels printing at 45 degree angle

[image]

getting this error

```
plt.bar(x-0.2, y1, width) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

my code is this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
L = ['AAAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFFFFFF', 'FGGGGG','HHHHHHHHHH']  
y1= [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215]
y2=[0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152]

width = 0.40
plt.bar(y1, width)
plt.bar(y2, width)

plt.legend(['one', 'two'], loc='upper right')
plt.xticks(x, L, rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You defined `x` as a list, you cannot subtract `0.2` from a list. Also the error you shared is not the result of the code you shared, since the actual line in the error is not in the code: `plt.bar(x-0.2, y1, width)` - instead you'd want something like `plt.bar([a-0.2 for a in x], y1, width)`

Comment: `x` is a list, and in Python doesn't support element-wise operations out of the box, you need to use something like this: `map(lambda v: v - 0.2, [1,2,3])`.

Comment: plt.bar([a-0.2 for a in x], y1, width)
plt.bar([a-0.2 for a in x], y2, width) its running i used this but its not printing grouped bars instead half bar is y1 value and hald bar is colored with y2 values

Comment: you cannot subtract a list and a float. they are different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List object is not allowed to broadcast operation

if you wanna broadcast, just warp numpy array object like below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
L = ['AAAAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEE', 'FFFFFFFFF', 'FGGGGG','HHHHHHHHHH']  
y1= [2232424, 2324353, 0, 8433232, 21421521, 2164216, 2761731,  752164215]
y2=[0, 32, 253, 6271, 263, 5535142, 1513153, 92512152]

width = 0.40
plt.bar(x - width/2, y1, width)
plt.bar(x + width/2, y2, width)

plt.legend(['one', 'two'], loc='upper right')
plt.xticks(x, L, rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks now the problem is my labels are getting cropped in the bar chart as they are length and in 30 degree rotation .. any suggestion how to solve this problem

Comment: @user12 That's a different problem, ask a different question. Did some research beforehand, and make a [example] for the question.